# How to auto close a java program if there's no user input for 5 minutes?

Tags: java, calculator

So, i need to create a calculator with auto turn-off after 5 minutes,if user does not interact with the program for 5 minutes, in java. I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody help please?

Comment: Is your calculator GUI??

Comment: [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 3):

If threads are a problem, you should be getting some sort of time difference in your render method. If not you will need to update a member with the time at interaction:

```
long msTimeLastUsed = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then in your event loop check that

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - msTimeLastUsed > 1000 * 60 * 5)
     System.exit(0);
```

I would advise to use threading only as a last resort, like when you need to push your CPU for all its got.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a background `Thread` that runs. This thread will have a `while` loop that can check every 30 seconds or so to see if the program has executed for more than 5 minutes. If so, then do a `System.exit(0)`. Stand by for implementation.

Edit: Here is the implementation. When the user is active, you would call the `active` method to reset the `lastActiveTime`.

In response to John's post, a `Thread` may be necessary when the Event loop is getting blocked waiting for I/O from the user.

```
class ExitIfInactive extends Thread { 
  private long lastActiveTime;
  private long timeout;

  public ExitIfInactive(long timeout) { 
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.active();
  }

  // call inside event loop to reset
  public void active() {
    this.lastActiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActiveTime > this.timeout) {
        System.exit(0);
      }

      try {                                                                                                                                           
        Thread.sleep(1000); // granularity to check
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.exit(-1); 
      }
    }
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExitIfInactive exitIfInactive = new ExitIfInactive(300_000L); // 5 minutes
    exitIfInactive.start();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to reset the timer after user have perform some activity.